# AOP and execute if annotation not present

Tags: java, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I am using AOP to wrap an auditing framework around some services.  I've come across an issue where we're auditing multiple events for the same action due to recursion.  The quick solution it to mark the method as `@NonAuditable` and add it to my pointcut strategy.  I am finding that the method still gets executed however.

Here's my existing strategy:

```
@Around(value="(" +
     "execution( * my.class.services..*.*(..)) " +
     ") && "+
     "@annotation(auditable)), argName="audit")
     public Object audit(ProceedingJoinPoint call, Audit audit) {
       ...
       ...
     }
```

How can I update my execution to say "only execute within the services package if it doesn't contain the `@NonAuditable` annotation?

I tried the following, which did not work:

```
@Around(value="(" +
 "execution( * my.class.services..*.*(..)) " +
 ") && "+
 "!@annotation(NonAuditable) && " +
 "@annotation(auditable), argName="audit")
 public Object audit(ProceedingJoinPoint call, Audit audit) {
   ...
   ...
 }
```

UPDATE:

Here are some examples of some methods that gets audited

```
package my.class.services.UserService
import ...
...

@Auditable(message="Request for user", Context="Search")
public User getUser(long id){
      User u = userRepository.getUser(id);
      ... // do work
}
```

\

```
package my.class.services.CarService
import ...
...

@Auditable(message="Request for traffic violations", Context="Search")
public List<Ticket> getTickets(long id){
      List<Ticket> tix = dmvRepository.getUserTicketsById(id);
      ... // do work
}

@NonAuditable(message="Request for traffic violations", Context="Search")
public List<Ticket> getSpeedingTickets(long id){
      List<Ticket> tickets = this.getTickets(id);
      Collection filter = Collection.filter(...);
      // do some other logic to just get speeding tickets.
      return filter;
}
```

One problem I inherited is that `getTickets` is being called recursively by another method (getSpeedingTickets) and I am looking to be able to apply an `Annotation` (`@NonAuditable`) on that method to stop `getTickets` from being audited.

Comment: I think I do not fully understand the problem, the explanation is unclear. Please add some sample code showing what kinds of methods you want audited and which ones not. I want to see methods, annotations, call hierarchies if possible.

Comment: Updated.  Please let me know if you need further details

Comment: I still do not understand. You want to have both `@Auditable` and `@NonAuditable` on the same method? Funny idea, but why? You are implying a solution - which probably will not work, by the way - instead of really describing your problem. I still do not see in the code the recursion problem you describe with words.

Comment: I think you should use just one annotation and in your pointcut either detect that it is present or missing `!@annotation(Auditable)`.

Comment: @kriegaex - I updated my example, so hopefully the question is more clear.

Comment: Are you serious? You updated the question after 1.5 years? That was "quick" feedback. I do not even remember this old question and will have to read everything again and see if I can find my old sample code anywhere. Looking at the last comments under my answer, I do not even know what is still unclear. What is not working? What in my aspect does not fit your problem description? Furthermore, you said "This is it!" about my solution, but still have not accepted it, even it exactly does what you asked for.

Comment: @kriegaex - I found a work around to the original question, however I wanted to provide feedback to others.  Using Spring AOP does not provide the "!cflow" annotation in the answer you gave - as I noted in the comment below.  This update is just to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I thought about it again and think I have guessed what you mean. I think your situation is like this:

**Annotations:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Auditable {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NonAuditable {}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.auditableAction("main");
        application.inBetweenAction("main");
        application.otherAction();
        application.nonAuditableAction();
    }

    @Auditable
    public void auditableAction(String caller) {
        System.out.println("  auditableAction called by " + caller);
    }

    @NonAuditable
    public void nonAuditableAction() {
        auditableAction("nonAuditableAction");
        inBetweenAction("nonAuditableAction");
    }

    public void otherAction() {
        auditableAction("otherAction");
        inBetweenAction("otherAction");
    }

    public void inBetweenAction(String caller) {
        auditableAction(caller + " via inBetweenAction");
    }
}
```

Now I assume you want to avoid auditing executions of the `@Auditable` method if called directly or indirectly by the `@NonAuditable` method. Correct? If so, the solution is to use a `cflow()` or `cflowbelow()` pointcut. Because such pointcuts cannot be evaluated statically but only dynamically during runtime, you might need to monitor the performance of your application after applying the aspect, but in many cases this is not a real problem. See for yourself. The solution looks as follows:

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class AuditAspect {
    @Around(
        "within(de.scrum_master.app..*) && " +
        "execution(* *(..)) && " +
        "@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.Auditable) && " +
        "!cflow(@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.NonAuditable))"
    )
    public Object audit(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.auditableAction(String))
  auditableAction called by main
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.auditableAction(String))
  auditableAction called by main via inBetweenAction
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.auditableAction(String))
  auditableAction called by otherAction
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.auditableAction(String))
  auditableAction called by otherAction via inBetweenAction
  auditableAction called by nonAuditableAction
  auditableAction called by nonAuditableAction via inBetweenAction
```

Please note that nothing is logged before the last two lines.

Comment: After running, I am getting contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'cflow', since those pointcut types are not supported in Spring.  Any thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: Of course. You need to use full [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) instead of Spring AOP (which is just a proxy-based "AOP lite" framework). The Spring manual explains how to use AspectJ via load-time weaving from within Spring in chapter [11.8 Using AspectJ with Spring applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj). Alternatively, you can also use compile-time weaving.

Comment: I looked over the docs and I think I'm more confused now.  I am a noob when it comes to AspectJ and the docs don't seem to be geared towards those without a greater breadth of experience.  If I just want to use cflowbelow in one Pointcut, which direction should I follow?

Comment: Most of the documentation expects you to be using XML configs, however all of ours are `@Bean`s and I cannot find our autoproxy annotation.

Comment: I am not a Spring user and neither able nor intending to give you a complete Spring + AspectJ course here. Besides, StackOverflow is not the right platform for tutorials anyway. But I do know that the documentation I pointed you to explains both XML-based and annotation-based ways of configuring AspectJ within Spring. Take your time to look over the manual and then start with a small example. Good luck.